# Hibernate Beginner Doubts

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

Hi I am new to hibernate. I read a lot of threads and discussions about which book and what specification to read. But the problem is some threads are so old that I don't understand where to start from. I started with Hibernate specification in Developer Guide which I think is too complicated. So I read some small tutorials. 
Actually I am assigned to some project where I was told that Hibernate is used. But because of little knowledge about Hibernate I am totally lost.  In the code I can see that in Maven pom Hibernate is used. I found META-INF/Persistence.xml which contains:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
 <persistence-unit name="EmployeeDatabase" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:EmpDS</jta-data-source>   
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
<class>entity.Employee</class> 
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="Usha" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Employee" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="Usha" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> 
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" /> 
    </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
```

I thought for hibernate configuration has to be done through hibernate.cfg.xml. But I coulnt find it anywhere. And in the code while doing queries there was no reference to hibernate. All the queries were done using import javax.persistence.Query. So I guess JPQL is used for doing the queries.

**So my question is : Is this really Hibernate or JPA or what??**

When can i say this is using Hibernate for persistence.

When to use JPQL and when to use HQL?

Please please can anyone guide me through this. Just be clear I want to learn Hibernate first and then dig further into my assignment. But I do not know where to start from. Which book  or tutorial is best .

Best Regards,
Jeena

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this really Hibernate or JPA or what?

JPA is a framework and Hibernate is an implementation that can use JPA framework. So do not confuse those together.

> When to use JPQL and when to use HQL?

Again JPQL is a standard language and is not only tied to Hibernate. However, if you are only using Hibernate you might find HQL to have more options and be more flexible.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language 
refer to this:

> JPQL is based on the Hibernate Query Language (HQL), an earlier
>   non-standard query language included in the Hibernate
>   object-relational mapping library.
>
> Hibernate and the HQL were created before the JPA specification. As of
>   Hibernate 3 JPQL is a subset of HQL.

Comment: thanks for the link. This is exactly same as the query operations I have in code. so that means we should use only JPQL as this is latest. But still my doubts about hibernate and JPA are there. So just to get things clear in my head. JPA is an API that provides different methods for CRUD on database. And Hibernate  provides the implementation of the these operations and actually executing those operations.??   It takes JPQL queries and interally converts them to SQL and gets back the result. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is : Is this really Hibernate or JPA or what??

This is JPA that uses Hibernate as implementation.

JPA is a standard, Hibernate is one of the implementation of JPA standard

Try to follow Hibernate documentation and tutorial, then use Hibernate EntityManager to make your project JPA compliant

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it.. As you said my first guess was also to start with Hibernate documentation. but found very difficult to follow.

Comment: And what about Persistence.xml vs hibernate.cfg.xml ? When can i use Persistence.xml? Because everywhere i read configuration is done through hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: If you want to have a JPA compliant application you must use the persistence.xml ( http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration ) and JPQL, so you can choose to switch from hibernate to any other JPA implementation (OpenJPA, EclipseLink, etc). If you want to use only hibernate then you dont need JPA, and you can use directly the hibernate.cfg.xml file and HQL, some more features but less portability.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is an implemantation for JPA. But Hiberante has more. There are other ways in hibernate to persist your objects to database. As mantioned, you can use JPA with other frameworks like [myBatis](http://blog.mybatis.org/).

In Hibernate using JPA is one option. When using JPA option you must use `EntityManager` and `EntityManagerFactory`. You must build your Factories using `persistance.xml`.

On the other hand you can use other options like `Criteria API` or `HQL`. When using Hibernate specific option, you must use `Session` and `SessionFactory`. And you must use `hibernate.cfg.xml` when creating  your SessionFactory.